# #define conversion from C to C#

Tags: c#, c, macros

Is this C code:

```
/* LERP(a,b,c) = linear interpolation macro, is 'a' when c == 0.0 and 'b' when c == 1.0 */
#define LERP(a,b,c)     (((b) - (a)) * (c) + (a))
```

http://www.brucelindbloom.com/index.html?Eqn_XYZ_to_T.html

Equals this C# code?

```
private static double LERP(double a, double b, double c) { return (((b) - (a)) * (c) + (a)); }
```

?

Comment: A bit too heavy on parenthesis there, but looks legit.

Comment: @bobobobo: What if an answer appears that you with your godlike opinion do not consider "nonsense", but your "nonsense-comment" is still there? Will you check this question's thread daily? This alone is enough proof to me that _your_ opinion is nonsense as for your non-defensive style of speaking, which prolly also reflects your style of programming. This holds doubly true with the fact that you don't know and/or respect the common justification for downvoting here on StackOverflow. Please never work in my company. At least not in IT.

Comment: Fine. Your answer is good, but the ones mentioning only the `++` corner case or the fact this would require conversion from integral types are not very useful.

Comment: @bobobobo: The increment operators are well defined for floating types, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

no.
consider the following:

`LERP(x++,1,2);`

The c code might also have a side effect of increasing x twice [it is undefined as mentioned by @phresnel], while the c# code is perfectly defined, and will increase x only once.

the result also might be different, since the first `a` and the second one [in the macro] might have a different value, since it might have increased in the first one.

Comment: +1, I.e. why one shouldn't use macros in the first place. But wanna bet a million bucks that the OP doesn't care about the corner case? :)

Comment: @Gleno: it smells like a homework question which is exactly looking for this corner case... anyway, one should also consider this thing

Comment: @amit Thx, didn't notice the corner case. anyway to fix it ?

Comment: @Danpe: use a function instead of the macro :)

Comment: Actually, that code has undefined meaning. Possibly, x is increased twice, possibly only once, possibly an exception is thrown.

Comment: @Danpe, don't bother with macro's corner case. You'll never want to use side effects of that case, and using function eliminates the problem completely.

Comment: -1 _no_ you should not consider this corner case. Nobody does ++ in calling a linear interpolate function anyway.

Comment: @bobobobo: Personal preference is not a reason for downvoting. And how do you know that the LERP functions was not exemplary, especially regarding the generic title `#define conversion from C to C#`?

Comment: @bobobobo: the OP asks if the 2 code samples are EQUAL, definition of equal: same behavior for all input cases. My answer aims to show an example where the behavior is different for the same input, and thus the 'functions' are not equal.

Comment: @amit: _"Actually, that code has undefined meaning. Possibly, x is increased twice, possibly only once, possibly an exception is thrown."_ -> I.e., _"the c code would also have a side effect of increasing x twice"_ is not correct as is, the C standard has no definition of multiple assignments to a single variable between two sequence points (my downvote still holds)

Comment: @phresnel: I editted my answer: changed will cause -> might cause, and added a reference to your answer.

Answer (score 9):

No. The C variant comes with all the deficiencies of `#define`-macros. Reminder:

```
#define LERP(a,b,c)     (((b) - (a)) * (c) + (a))
```

### Potential Waste of Performance

Imagine a [pure function call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) in an invokation of the `#define`-macro:

```
int fac (int x) {
    return x<=1 ? 1 : x*fac(x-1);
}

int main () {
    std::cout << LERP(fac(5), fac(2), 0);
}
```

That line expands to:

```
    std::cout << (((fac(2)) - (fac(5))) * (0) + (fac(5)))
```

Now you have potentially doubled the runtime for two invokations of your faculty function that was perviously just one.

This surely gets worse if you nest your lerping, as is for instance common in some graphics programming situations:

```
int main () {
    std::cout << LERP(
                     LERP(fac(5), fac(2), 0),
                     LERP(fac(5), fac(2), 0),
                     0
                 );
}
```

Expanding to:

```
int main () {
    std::cout << LERP(
                     (((fac(2)) - (fac(5))) * (0) + (fac(5))),
                     (((fac(2)) - (fac(5))) * (0) + (fac(5)))
                     0
                 );
}
```

Expanding to (formatting tweaked for readability):

```
int main () {
    std::cout << (  (((((fac(2)) - (fac(5))) * (0) + (fac(5))))
                  - ((((fac(2)) - (fac(5))) * (0) + (fac(5)))))
                  * (c)
                 + ((((fac(2)) - (fac(5))) * (0) + (fac(5)))))
}
```

Whereas the clean version does computationally not more than:

```
float a = LERP(fac(5), fac(2), 0);
float b = LERP(fac(5), fac(2), 0);
float c = LERP(a,b,0);
```

or

```
float fac_a = fac(5),
      fac_b = fac(2);
float a = (fac_b-fac_a)*0 + fac_a;
float fac_c = fac(5),
      fac_d = fac(2);
float a = (fac_d-fac_c)*0 + fac_c;
```

So in a two dimensional setup

1. Proper version:

   1. 4 calls to `fac()`
   2. 4 additions
   3. 2 multiplications
2. ´#define` version:

   1. 9 calls to `fac()`
   2. 8 additions
   3. 4 multiplications

It gets exponentially worse with every dimension you'd add. Even five-dimensional [Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) is sometimes seen (3d volume + time + continous seed), ***[for which some expressions are evaluated freaking 31 times, instead of just once!](http://ideone.com/8YkeM)***:

```
LERP( LERP(LERP(LERP(LERP(probe(),1,2), LERP(3,4,5), 6),
                LERP(LERP(7,8,9), LERP(10,11,12), 13),
                14),
           LERP(LERP(LERP(90,91,92), LERP(93,94,95), 96),
                LERP(LERP(97,98,99), LERP(910,911,912), 913),
                914),
           1014),
      LERP(LERP(LERP(LERP(0,1,2), LERP(3,4,5), 6),
                LERP(LERP(7,8,9), LERP(10,11,12), 13),
                14),
          LERP(LERP(LERP(90,91,92), LERP(93,94,95), 96),
               LERP(LERP(97,98,99), LERP(910,911,912), 913),
               914),
          1014),
      666)
```

You can also see the preprocessed code by invoking `cpp` (note the single appearance of `probe()` before).

```
foo@bar:~/ cpp heavy.cc
```

> [snip] (((((((((((((((911) - (910)) * (912) + (910))) - ((((98) - (97)) * (99) + (97)))) * (913) + ((((98) - (97)) * (99) + (97))))) - (((((((94) - (93)) * (95) + (93))) - ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))) * (96) + ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))))) * (914) + (((((((94) - (93)) * (95) + (93))) - ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))) * (96) + ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90))))))) - ((((((((((11) - (10)) * (12) + (10))) - ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7)))) * (13) + ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7))))) - (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (0)) * (2) + (0)))) * (6) + ((((1) - (0)) * (2) + (0)))))) * (14) + (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (0)) * (2) + (0)))) * (6) + ((((1) - (0)) * (2) + (0)))))))) * (1014) + ((((((((((11) - (10)) * (12) + (10))) - ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7)))) * (13) + ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7))))) - (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (0)) * (2) + (0)))) * (6) + ((((1) - (0)) * (2) + (0)))))) * (14) + (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (0)) * (2) + (0)))) * (6) + ((((1) - (0)) * (2) + (0))))))))) - (((((((((((((911) - (910)) * (912) + (910))) - ((((98) - (97)) * (99) + (97)))) * (913) + ((((98) - (97)) * (99) + (97))))) - (((((((94) - (93)) * (95) + (93))) - ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))) * (96) + ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))))) * (914) + (((((((94) - (93)) * (95) + (93))) - ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))) * (96) + ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90))))))) - ((((((((((11) - (10)) * (12) + (10))) - ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7)))) * (13) + ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7))))) - (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))) * (6) + ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))))) * (14) + (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))) * (6) + ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))))))) * (1014) + ((((((((((11) - (10)) * (12) + (10))) - ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7)))) * (13) + ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7))))) - (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))) * (6) + ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))))) * (14) + (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))) * (6) + ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))))))))) * (666) + (((((((((((((911) - (910)) * (912) + (910))) - ((((98) - (97)) * (99) + (97)))) * (913) + ((((98) - (97)) * (99) + (97))))) - (((((((94) - (93)) * (95) + (93))) - ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))) * (96) + ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))))) * (914) + (((((((94) - (93)) * (95) + (93))) - ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90)))) * (96) + ((((91) - (90)) * (92) + (90))))))) - ((((((((((11) - (10)) * (12) + (10))) - ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7)))) * (13) + ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7))))) - (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))) * (6) + ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))))) * (14) + (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))) * (6) + ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))))))) * (1014) + ((((((((((11) - (10)) * (12) + (10))) - ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7)))) * (13) + ((((8) - (7)) * (9) + (7))))) - (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))) * (6) + ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))))) * (14) + (((((((4) - (3)) * (5) + (3))) - ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe())))) * (6) + ((((1) - (probe())) * (2) + (probe()))))))))))

Again, full source [is here](http://ideone.com/8YkeM).

### Potential Undefined Behaviour

You can put evil stuff into it:

```
LERP(++a,b,c)
```

which expands to

```
(((b) - (++a)) * (c) + (++a))
```

which is undefined behaviour in C¹ (and in C++, btw). `a` might be increased twice, or it might be increased once, or an exception might be thrown that says `Debug-Runtime-Exception: Invoked Undefined Behaviour`, or the compiler is smart enough to reject that code, or whatever.

The undefined behaviour comes from the fact that the C99-standard (and C++2003, too) does not allow a value to be modified multiple times before reaching the next [Sequence Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

### ID pollution and infection

*(This is more relevant if you'd convert the C# into the macro variant.)*

The `#define`-macro-name pollutes and infects the whole unit of translation from the point of definition to either the end-of-unit or its undefinition.

```
foo@bar:~/ cat main.cc
// Orbiter Physics Sim
#include "lerp.h"

int main () {
    const int LERP = 2; // Linear Extrasolar Resonance Potential.
}

foo@bar:~/ g++ main.cc
main.cc:5:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
```

### More ...

- Macros are generic, but not typesafe. The macro-writer has no (clean) opportunity to put constraints on the types for which that macro should be valid.
- Macros don't have scope, though this is already implied by the last section

---

¹: C99 (ISO/IEC 9899:TC2), J.2, "Undefined Behaviour": `Between two sequence points, an object is modified more than once, or is modified and the prior value is read other than to determine the value to be stored (6.5).`

Comment: I think the issue you are pointing at applies only to c++, isn't it  perfectly defined in c? [the question is labled as 'c', not 'c++']

Comment: Also applies to C99. See section J2, a summary of "Undefined behaviour": `Between two sequence points, an object is modified more than once, or is modified and the prior value is read other than to determine the value to be stored (6.5).`

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that, thx for point out my C/C++ confusion :)

Answer (score 5):

Technically, no they are not equal. The C macro can take any type: `int`, `float`, `byte`, etc.

Your C# version can only handle double, without explicit casts. You'd need to add overloads as needed for other types.

Comment: LERP is very nearly useless on an integral type

Comment: @bobobobo: So? It still can take any type for which those operators are defined. Apart, only this incarnation of linear interpolation is useless. But generally, lerping integers is perfectly valid. You just need some divisions or bitshifts. I've done so in metatrace, for example, a compile time ray tracer based on fixed point math (and integers can be considered a subset of fixed point numbers).

Comment: @bobobobo: Question: If you were the one to downvote this correct answer, then you must be really inexperienced w.r.t. programming and the stack overflow community.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically equivalent, yes. You can also get rid of some parentheses:

```
private static double LERP(double a, double b, double c) { return (b - a) * c + a; }
```

Comment: It is not basically equivalent. Macros are not type-safe.

Comment: I interpreted the question as "if I rewrite it this way, does it do the same calculation?".

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not how it is written.

Comment: Sometimes we just have to read minds and answer the question that should have been asked. OP needs a function in C# that is equivalent to macro in C, and this is that equivalent function.

Comment: @Dialecticus: I understand what you are saying, but an equivalent set of functions would have all the overloads. Macros take in *anything*. Also, this is not equivalent because there is a side-effect with macros as shown in the current highest upvoted answer.

Comment: @Code Monkey: Value c must be double in any way, therefore the result should be double as well. Whatever the a and b may be they must safely be converted to double for function to make sense. So if they must be converted then they can be converted on function invocation. So, in this case, "triple-double" combination is the only one that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

To get what you had in C you may use:

```
delegate double ValueGetter();
static double LERP(ValueGetter a, ValueGetter b, ValueGetter c) { return (b() - a()) * c() + a(); }
```

But I agree with amit. This might be the same you had in C (but solely for double not for other types) still it might not be what you really want.. (with delegate you could set 'i++' as a, not only result of i++)

Comment: But still, the result of the C version `LERP(i++,...` is simply not defined, so an exact duplicate can't be possible with regards to multiple assignments.

Comment: That's true. My example is not even generic. But even if it was it wouldn't cover all possibilities of macros.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you can write it more simple:

```
return (b - a) * c + a;
```

Comment: -1: actually they are not equal, as the other answers point out (which comes from deficiencies of `#define`-macros)

Comment: @phresnel - this C# code works like correctly used macro, and gives compilation error, when used incorrectly. Is it OK for you? With 40% of negative votes you are close to have the Troll badge.

Comment: the question was whether they are equivalent, and I am afraid they are not. What is "correctly used"? For example: `centers[x] = lerp(++minsIter, ++maxsIter, 0.5);`, that does not even look foul to me. And it's a possible use for the C# version, but not for the C-Macro version. Troll badge: You are right, I must up-vote more.